# Unable to retrieve actual Credentials from CustomRegistry while starting WAS 6.1

Tags: websphere, jaas

I am facing the authentication issue, even I am using correct credentials, when trying to start Web Sphere. 
To start application we configured Custom Registry for enabling login module security. Below is the configuration in Security.xml in Appserver/profiles/profile1/config/cells/###Node02Cell/security.xml

```
<userRegistries xmi:type="security:CustomUserRegistry" xmi:id="CustomUserRegistry_1" serverId="Admin" serverPassword="{xor}xxxxx" realm="customRealm" limit="0" ignoreCase="false" useRegistryServerId="true" primaryAdminId="" customRegistryClassName="com.s1.arch.security.realm.websphere.GenericRegistry"/>
```

and below are the configured login modules

```
<systemLoginConfig>
<loginModules xmi:id="JAASLoginModule_1264755872404" moduleClassName="com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule" >
        <options xmi:id="Property_1264755872888" name="cookie" value="true" required="true"/>
        </loginModules>
    <loginModules xmi:id="JAASLoginModule_1264755873404" moduleClassName="com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.wsMapDefaultInboundLoginModule" >
        <options xmi:id="Property_1264755874013" name="cookie" value="true" required="true"/>
        </loginModules>
</SystemloginConfig>
```

Below are error details.

Unable to get actual credentials

```
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getServerSubjectInternal(ContextManagerImpl.java:2212)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getServerSubjectInternal(ContextManagerImpl.java:1972)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.initialize(ContextManagerImpl.java:2530)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.auth.WSLoginFailedException
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:800)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.server.lm.ltpaLoginModule.login(ltpaLoginModule.java:453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:795)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:209)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:246)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:706)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.JaasLoginHelper.jaas_login(JaasLoginHelper.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3513)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3306)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.login(ContextManagerImpl.java:3086)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.getServerSubjectInternal(ContextManagerImpl.java:2180)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.security.PasswordCheckFailedException
    at com.s1.arch.security.realm.websphere.GenericRegistry.checkPassword(GenericRegistry.java:40)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.registry.UserRegistryImpl.checkPassword(UserRegistryImpl.java:309)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.ltpa.LTPAServerObject.authenticate(LTPAServerObject.java:775)
```

As a work around I skipped this security configuration, then I am able to start the server with out any issues and I installed my application. But while trying login from application login page, I am getting below issue.

**No Login modules found**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As you dont have to create LoginModules to use Custom user registry, and also the other way around. Currently it looks like your failing in your CUR implementation - `GenericRegistry.checkPassword(GenericRegistry.java:40)`

Comment: Thanks for comments. I am quite new to Websphere. My problem is suddenly we are not able to authenticate in Generic Registry, even with correct credentials. What might be the causes. The login modules are already created. When I am disabling this security,I am able to open application login page(i.e in browser using localhot:9086/login.jsp). While trying to login it is giving error message, no login modules found. How can I skip login module authentication also.I hope it is clear.

Comment: As I already wrote, check your class `GenericRegistry` why it is failing in line 40. Probably the password is different, maybe someone changed that and you are not aware of that.